# Help with a SQL query

Tags: sql

How would I go about this? I have 3 rows like so:

```
ID         THREAD         POST
1            1              Hello World
2            2              Hello galaxy
3            2              Hello people
```

I need to return ID, Thread, and Post once for each thread only using the lowest ID.

something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE THREAD DISTINT AND ID = MIN(ID)
```

Edit: To be more clear in this example it should only return the rows for 1 and 2 because 3 isn't the lowest ID with a Thread of 2

Edit 2: it needs to return both rows 1 and 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL Server 2005 and beyond:

```
SELECT t.Id, t.Thread, t.Post
FROM 
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Thread ORDER BY Id) as RowNumInThread
FROM table
) t
WHERE t.RowNumInThread = 1
;
```

or

```
SELECT t.*
FROM 
(
  SELECT Min(Id) as MinId
  FROM table
  GROUP BY Thread
) tmin
JOIN
table t   ON t.Id = tmin.Id
;
```

Comment: need to return ID, Thread, and Post once **for each thread only using the lowest ID**

Comment: Yes, that's what my query does. For each partition of Threads, return the row which has RowNumInThread set to 1.

Comment: And for the second query, I'm grouping by Thread, therefore the subquery is returning any ID which is the minimum one for a group. It looks very much from the sample data that Id is a unique field, so I don't need to return Thread from the subquery.

Comment: Your answer is also valid, but if Id is actually unique, then checking Thread is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks buddy...it's help me..this type of question asked in today interview

Answer (score 2):

```
select id, thread, post
from t
inner join (
select min(id)
from t
group by thread) subq on t.id = subq.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

```
SELECT  t.*
FROM    Table t INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  MIN(ID) MINID,
                    Thread
            FROM    Table
            GROUP BY  Thread
        ) sub   ON  t.ID = sub.MINID 
                AND t.Thread = sub.Thread
```

Comment: Typo... you don't mean tempdb.Thread, you mean t.Thread. Intellisense error I'm guessing...

Comment: Thanx, Sql Server 2008 Intellisense can be both good and bad X-)